# Why we should use BindingSource with gridview when it works if i directly assign dataset to it?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I was studing ADO.NET in C#.
I am not sure if I have proper concept of binding source or not. As in case of asp.net we use

```
gridview1.DataBind();
```

So I thought in case of windows application I have to use like this.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource= ds.Tables[0];
gridveiw1.DataSource = bs;
```

here ds is DataSet.

But if I am using like this..

```
gridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

its also working.

Then why we should use Binding Source. What features binding source will allow over without using it or there is no need of binding source here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BindingSource was developed in .Net 2.0 while the DataSet / DataTable classes came first in .Net 1.1

From [BindingSource and BindingList Of T - DataBinding made simple!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dchandnani/archive/2005/03/12/394438.aspx)

> Of course you can bind the DataGridView to the DataTable directly and bypass the BindingSource, but BindingSource has certain advantages:
>
> - It exposes properties to Sort the list, Filter the list, etc. which would other wise be a pain to do. (i.e. if you bind the DataGridView to the DataTable directly then to Sort the DataTable you need to know that DataTable is an IListSource which knows the underlying list which is a DataView and a DataView can be sorted, filtered, etc.).
> - If you have to set up master/child views then BindingSource does a great job of doing this